# Xcode Swift Templates Lower Camel Case

Tags: swift, xcode, templates

I know how to make templates for ViewControllers, ViewModels, etc that get named based on the file name that the user inputs when they create the file, however I haven't found a way to force some variables to have lower camel case.

So basically I want to create my VC file with some variables inside of it and obviously those variables will depend on the file name (upper camel case) for their type, but lower camel case for their names.

Example:

```
class FileNameViewController {
    var fileNameViewModel: FileNameViewModelDelegate?
}

class FileNameViewModel {
    var fileNameViewController: FileNameViewControllerDelegate?
}

protocol FileNameViewControllerDelegate {
    ...
}

protocol FileNameViewModelDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to have the template fill in the variable names in lower camel case and the types in upper camel case based on the file's name?

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to process Xcode template text macros outside of supported modifiers (described [Xcode official doc](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devc8a500cb9))...

However I found convenient the following approach (adopting to your example):

```
//___FILEHEADER___

import Foundation

class ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewController {
    var model___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___: ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewModelDelegate?
}

class ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewModel {
    var controller___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___: ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewControllerDelegate?
}

protocol ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewControllerDelegate {
}

protocol ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ViewModelDelegate {
}
```

For `Card` file name it generates:

```
//
//  Card.swift

import Foundation

class CardViewController {
    var modelCard: CardViewModelDelegate?
}

class CardViewModel {
    var controllerCard: CardViewControllerDelegate?
}

protocol CardViewControllerDelegate {
}

protocol CardViewModelDelegate {
}
```